# Function that returns an int value, instead of a string in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm trying to write a function in C that gets an int as a parameter and returns a char array (or a string).

```
const char * month(int x)
{
    char result[40];
    if(x<=31) strcpy(result,"can be a day of the month");
    else strcpy(result,"cannot be a day of the month");
    return result;
}
```

But my function returns an int, not a string. I have read posts where people might have run into similar situations, but I can't understand how the pointer-type functions work and how to make them return what I want (I have documented a bit about pointers and I have an idea about how they work alone, but I have never tried to write a piece of code that adds some functionality to them, like making a solution more effective or something else.)

Comment: `result` in an object with automatic scope that gets destroyed when the function returns. The returned pointer is invalid, and dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: `result` goes out of scope and life when the function exits. There are many SO question like this.

Comment: Is this C code or C++ code? The answers for the two languages are completely different.

Comment: Make up your mind with the tags -- some the approaches that are normal for C are things you usually really shouldn't do in C++. Conversely, some of the things you would do in C++ you *can't* do in C.

Comment: this code is written in C

Comment: Possible duplicate of -- oops, never mind. So many to choose from (instead of answering yet again!) and I stillmanaged to pick a wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this is a C code. (not sure if C++)
Your best choice here is to have `result` declared outside the function scope and then pass a pointer inside the function that you are using that you can fill with your data (be sure to **not overflow**). In what you are using, `result` will be destroyed and you won't be able to use it.

```
void month(int x, char* result)
{
    if(x<=31) strcpy(result,"can be a day of the month");
    else strcpy(result,"cannot be a day of the month")
}
```

That was only a suggestion you could return instead some error code or whatever you want.

Comment: In order to store the value of the result, do I need a char[] type or a string when I call the function in int main()? I know it's a stupid question but I haven't worked with pointers before.

Comment: Assuming you are using C and not C++, there is no string support in C so you need char[] declared.

Comment: It works totally fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
const char * month(int x)
{
    char result[40];
    if(x<=31) strcpy(result,"can be a day of the month");
    else strcpy(result,"cannot be a day of the month");
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't make sense. You return a pointer to the array, but after the function returns, the array no longer exists since `result` is local to the function.

For C:

```
const char * month(int x)
{
    if(x<=31) return "can be a day of the month";
    return "cannot be a day of the month";
}
```

For C++:

```
std::string month(int x)
{
    if(x<=31) return "can be a day of the month";
    return "cannot be a day of the month";
}
```